# Sharing a Docker container directory which serves as a mount point

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container which has a mount point at `/ofs`, which points at an ObjectiveFS volume that is stored in AWS S3. The ObjectiveFS volume containes some files.

Following is the relevant output from within the container:

```
root@d817213fe73a:/ofs# mount
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-263633-d817213fe73ac81cafa7e5c7ab45567835327a27d2b5e57aef496a28e5398c47 on / type xfs (rw,relatime,nouuid,attr2,inode64,logbsize=128k,sunit=256,swidth=1024,noquota)
...
s3://<my_s3_bucket> on /ofs type fuse.objectivefs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)

root@d817213fe73a:/ofs# ls -l /ofs
total 2
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 605 Apr 26 17:33 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20 Apr 26 18:00 test.txt
root@d817213fe73a:/ofs#
```

I would like to share the data in `/ofs` with another container.

I've tried creating a Docker volume at `/ofs` in the first container and share it with the second container by using `docker run -v /ofs first_container` and `docker run --volumes-from first_container second_container`, however when doing so the files at `/ofs` don't show up in the volume's directory on the host, and therefore the other container can't access them:

```
[root@ip-172-17-1-106 ~]# ls -al /var/lib/docker/volumes/209cc29d6046d80db80194650871173bc137061de1d8c509a45a32c8142e5306/_data/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  1 15:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May  1 15:23 ..
[root@ip-172-17-1-106 ~]#
```

Following is the output of `findmnt /ofs` from the first container:

```
root@2d3c0f90f46d:/ofs# findmnt /ofs
TARGET SOURCE                                                                                                     FSTYPE           OPTIONS
/ofs   /dev/xvda1[/var/lib/docker/volumes/209cc29d6046d80db80194650871173bc137061de1d8c509a45a32c8142e5306/_data] ext4             rw,noatime,data=ordered
/ofs   s3://<my_s3_bucket>                                                                             fuse.objectivefs rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permis
root@2d3c0f90f46d:/ofs#
```

Following is the relevant `docker inspect` output for both containers:

**First container**

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/var/lib/docker/volumes/209cc29d6046d80db80194650871173bc137061de1d8c509a45a32c8142e5306/_data:/ofs"
    ]
},
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/209cc29d6046d80db80194650871173bc137061de1d8c509a45a32c8142e5306/_data",
        "Destination": "/ofs",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true
    }
]
```

**Second container**

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/var/app/current/php-app:/var/www/html:ro"
    ]
},
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/209cc29d6046d80db80194650871173bc137061de1d8c509a45a32c8142e5306/_data",
        "Destination": "/ofs",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true
    },
    {
        "Source": "/var/app/current/php-app",
        "Destination": "/var/www/html",
        "Mode": "ro",
        "RW": false
    }
]
```

Any idea how to share the `/ofs` directory on the first container with the second container when `/ofs` serves as a mount point?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question unclear or illegitimate?

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted, it seemed fine to me.

Comment: Can you see the volume files in the first container? Or are they not visible in any of the containers?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear in the question, which output snippets went with the host, vs first container or second container

Comment: @KenCochrane I can see the files in the first container, however I can't see them on the host or the second container. In other words, I can see the files under `/ofs` in the first container the same way I can see them when I don't create a volume at `/ofs`. I edited the question. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I've found something which might be useful - the output of `findmnt /ofs` in the first container shows two entries. I've added the output to the original post.

Comment: When you create the volume for the container try setting both the container dir and the host dir. `docker run -v /host/dir:/ofs` and see if the files are available on the host then

Comment: @KenCochrane I've done that and I can't see the files on the host.

Comment: I've found a similar issue which happens when mounting an NFS volume inside a container and then trying to access it from another container: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4213

Comment: Did the suggestions in that issue help at all?

Comment: Didn't manage to get it to work yet, but I think the issue might help understand the problem. Looks like in the NFS case the problem was related to shared mount flags or something similar. I'm not familiar with the topic so I'm looking into it. Promise to update here once I have updates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to mounting the volume directly on the host and sharing it with the container?

`docker run -it -v /ofs:/ofs ubuntu`

Comment: Yes. The container had an empty `/ofs` directory.